# MySQL query / Hibernate Mapping not giving expected results

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

In my database, each user has a department and a userlevel. These are denoted in the users table with their department_id and their userlevel_id. The corresponding User java classes also has a department and userlevel field.

I need to select all the users from my db with a given username and password, and automatically map their department and userlevel object to their User object.

I have my Users, Departments and Userlevels class (automatically generated by hibernate pojo mapping) as follows:

```
public class Users  implements java.io.Serializable {
private Integer id;
 private Departments departments;
 private Userlevels userlevels;
 private String username;
 private String password;
 private String salt;
 private String email;
 private String firstName;
 private String lastName;

public Users() {
}

   //Getters and setters
}

public class Departments  implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
     private String name;

    public Departments() {
    }
        //Getters and Setters
    }
}

public class Userlevels  implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer id;
     private String name;

    public Userlevels() {
    }
        //Getters and Setters
    }
}
```

I have an SQL query as such:

```
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT u.*,d.*,ul.* FROM users u, departments d, userlevels ul WHERE u.department_id=d.id AND u.userlevel_id=ul.id AND u.username=? AND u.password=?");

q.setString(0, "usernameToGet");
q.setString(1, "passwordToGet");
q.addEntity("u", Users.class);
q.addJoin("dept", "u.departments");
q.addJoin("ulevels", u.userlevels");

List<Users> users = q.list();
```

Right now I'm getting the correct User object with its corresponding department object, but the userlevels object is returning null....
Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!!

Comment: I'm using Hibernate in Netbeans and all the mapping is done automatically. I'm pretty sure I don't need any extra annotations...however I could be wrong

Comment: What kind of Exception do you get now?

Comment: Right now I'm getting the correct User object with its corresponding department object, but the userlevels object is returning null....

Comment: what is the result of your SQLQeury ?

Comment: You really need to learn about JPA/Hibernate. Yes, you need annotations in your entity classes (or XML mapping, but that is completely obsolete), and no, you shouldn't use SQL to create queries, but HQL: `select u from User u where u.username = :name AND u.password = :password`. Also, rename your entity classes so that they use the singular form. User instead of Users, Department instead of Departments, etc.